# Non-trivial abelian subgroup of $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ must be infinite cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ is the proper non-trivial  subgroup of  $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$, whether $G$ must be  infinite cyclic ?

What I try: $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ can be treated as integral vector of $\mathbb R^2$.  And the proper subspace of $R^2$ are the lines through the origin. The integral vector on  a line is an infinite cyclic group. So I think  the proper non-trivial  subgroup of  $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ must be infinite cyclic.

I forgot almost all about abstract algebra and only find the concepts from Wikipedia,  I am not sure about my interpretation. So I want to know if it's right. Thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z} \oplus 2\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is certainly a proper and nontrivial subgroup, but is not cyclic.

Comment: The proper subspace stuff really only makes sense when you’re dealing with vector spaces. Otherwise a proper free submodule of a free module could have the same dimension.

Comment: Your very terse discussion of the problem, together with a lack of information about where you encountered this exercise, creates a difficulty for your Readers in guessing how best to help.  Perhaps you should tell us about what proper non-trivial subgroups you can think of, and how they address the problem posed here.